# Performance, load and stress testing in Django

Tags: python, django, testing, performance-testing

I am studying the different types of testing for a Django application. I know how to do functional and unit testing in Django and how to apply different methodologies, but now I am facing a new challenge, I need to know how to do:

- Performance testing
- Load testing
- Stress testing

I **know the difference between them** but I dont know which is the best methodology to follow,which are the best packages for do it or simply where I can get some **documentation** about it.

So my question is, how can I start to do these types of tests in a Django app or where can I get some good documentation about it?

Thanks

Comment: Performance testing is a category.  A load test is a specific test with a defined number of users at a defined level of production. A stress test is a test of constantly increasing load to the point of defined failure.   See TPC.org for the TPC-C benchmark as an example of a load test

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) and [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) are basically performance testing sub-types where:

- Load testing: is putting the system under **anticipated** load to see whether performance metrics like response time or throughput match expectations/[SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)s
- Stress testing: is determining system boundaries and/or bottlenecks, i.e. you start the "normal" load test and increase the load until monitored metrics exceed acceptable thresholds or errors start occurring (whatever comes first)

Also, be aware of [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) - when you put the system under a **prolonged** load to see if it is capable of handling sustained concurrent usage. The majority of [bottlenecks](https://blog.smartbear.com/code-review/identify-performance-bottlenecks-in-your-source-code/) are being discovered during Soak Testing phase.

---

With regards to "how do I":

1. First of all you need a performance testing tool. Given `python` and `django` tags my expectation is that you find [Locust](https://locust.io/) tool interesting as you will be able to write your tests in some form of Python language. You can also consider [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) where you can write tests in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (Java bindings for Python) language so you won't have to learn the new tool from scratch. Other free and open source load testing tools are listed and compared in the [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)
2. Next step will be creating a load test scenario. You need to mimic real application usage as closely as possible, to wit you need to properly simulate real users using a real browser with all related stuff like:

   - cookies
   - headers
   - cache
   - think times
   - AJAX requests
   - embedded resources handling (images, scripts, styles, fonts)
3. Once you have the test and have the confidence regarding it is doing what it is supposed to be doing you can run it with an increased number of users and see how does your application behave under the load, correlate increasing/decreasing load with changing metrics/resources usage

Comment: Right now k6 have grown in popularity for load testing + cloud offering